# ещё -vs- всё ещё

Tags: словоупотребление

I have a habit of using **всё ещё** in situations that call for "still" or "yet" in English. Apparently in my mind they're interchangeable, with a leaning towards **всё ещё** as the default in all cases. Natives are continuously correcting this back to bare **ещё**. I've tried to find rules for the usage of these terms and wasn't successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you confusing *всё ещё* with *вcё* or *ещё*? Either the title or the body is misleading.

Comment: I think it's similar to: "She/He is still XXX" vs. "She still has XXX";  "всё ещё" - stronger form ( "he still has not married")

Comment: всё = everything, all

ещё = more, yet, still—"more" is the base meaning in my opinion 

всё + ещё = EVERYTHING still = (Stronger version, like He's STILL here, omg!) (Or I'm STILL here and I'm not going away).

Take the literal meaning and add your own flavor on top of that and you get the feeling for most of these constructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ещё" version tends to be used in a situation when something doesn't happen for the reason it's a bit early for it to happen. The "всё ещё" version has a slight hint in it that the time has come for something to happen but it still doesn't happen.

```
Она ещё не замужем. (probably she's a young girl)

Она всё ещё не замужем. (sounds like she's not too young at that)
```